# Downloading only one band in Google Earth Engine without the RGB bands

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, rendering, multi-band, rgb

I have calculted the NDVI of specific plot and download it in order to run analysis in QGIS. The image on GEE had only one band: the calculted NDVI, but whenever I open it on QGIS I have 4 bands: NDVI and the RGB bands. I would like to have only one band in the image.

Is there any way to download only one band and not to have the rendered image?

This is an example for how I have download image that has only band 4 and band 8 and QA60, but when I  opened it on QGIS I had also the RGB:

[image]

This is the code part the export the images:

```
for (var i in listOfNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize({}).addBands(image);


//   // do what ever you need with image
  Map.addLayer(image, {}, i);
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: toexport.toFloat(),
  description: i,
  scale:20,
  crs:'EPSG:4326',
  //maxPixels:1310361348,
  region:geometry.geometry().bounds()

});


}
```

Comment: Please show the Earth Engine code you used to download the image. An image _export_ should not contain bands that weren't present in the input image, but some operations do create "visualization" RGB bands.

Comment: @Kevin Reid I have edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want RGB visualization bands, then you should not call `image.visualize({})`. The `visualize` algorithm creates RGB bands.

Simply replace `image.visualize({}).addBands(image)`, which adds the original bands back to the visualization bands, with `image`. The `toFloat` will probably also be unneeded then.

```js
for (var i in listOfNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  Map.addLayer(image, {}, i);
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: i,
    scale: 20,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    region: geometry.geometry().bounds()
  });
}
```